# Factory class returning a generic interface

Tags: c#, design-patterns, generics, factory

I have few concrete which uses the following type of interface

```
interface IActivity<T>
{
    bool Process(T inputInfo);
}
```

Concrete classes are like as follows

```
class ReportActivityManager :IActivity<DataTable>
{
    public bool Process(DataTable inputInfo)
    {
        // Some coding here
    }
}

class AnalyzerActivityManager :IActivity<string[]>
{
    public bool Process(string[] inputInfo)
    {
        // Some coding here
    }
}
```

Now how can i write the factory class which retuns a generic interface some thing like IActivity.

```
class Factory
{
    public IActivity<T> Get(string module)
    {
        // ... How can i code here
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Getting error.. error CS0050: Inconsistent accessibility: return type

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should create generic method, otherwise compiler will not know type of `T` in return value. When you will have `T` you will be able to create activity based on type of `T`:

```
class Factory
{
    public IActivity<T> GetActivity<T>()
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        if (type == typeof(DataTable))
            return (IActivity<T>)new ReportActivityManager();
        // etc
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
IActivity<DataTable> activity = factory.GetActivity<DataTable>();
```

Comment: I'm getting an error "error CS0050: Inconsistent accessibility: return type"

Comment: Also getting Cannot implicitly convert type 'Factory.ReportActivityManager' to 'Factory.IActivity<T>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: It worked fine.. But i want to know why its throwing and error when i make the class as public.. the error thrown is Inconsistent accessibility: return type Factory.Managers.IActivityManager<T>' is less accessible than method 'Factory.Managers.Factory.GetActivity<T>()'

Comment: @Anish because your `IActivity<T>` interface has `internal` visibility. You should make it public also.

Comment: @Anish welcome :) Btw consider to use dependency injection framework. E.g. with ninject you can bind your managers like this `Bind<IActivity<DataTable>>().To<ReportActivityManager>();` and then retrieve instance this way: `IActivity<DataTable> activity = kernel.Get<IActivity<DataTable>>();`

Comment: This definitely looks like service locator to me. Here's a [blog post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/11/01/PatternRecognitionAbstractFactoryorServiceLocator/) that explains the subtle difference between an abstract factory and service locator.

Comment: @Sean thanks, good link. And agree, this API looks like service locator. Also I want to add one big difference between factory and service locator, which is not in the post - usually (or even always) factories create new objects, and they have methods called `Create`. On the other hand service locator just locates where service sits and returns reference to service. I.e. if we use singleton, then single instance of service will be used over application. That's why service locators usually have methods named `Get` instead of `Create`, because that will be confusing

Answer (score 1):

Often this is implemented as in [lazyberezovsky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13250517/112407). In c++ you could use template specialization to get compiler errors when you try to create a type the factory does not handle.

You can't do that in C# but you can get close. Though the code might look a little surprising which in turn could be a problem.

```
public static class Factory {
   public static IActivity<someType> Get(this someType self){
          //stuff specific to someType
   }

   public static IActivity<someOtherType> Get(someOtherType self){
          //stuff specific to someOtherType
   }

   public static T Creator<T>(){
        return null;
   }

}
```

The usage would then be

```
IActivity<someType> act = Factory.Creator<someType>().Get();
```

of course this only works if you can pass a concrete type. If you need to pass a type parameter things get more complicated.

Comment: I'm not great with C#, but is it just an oversight that the second one isn't an extension method?

Comment: Also, regarding "you could use template specialization to get compiler errors when you try to create a type the factory does not handle", couldn't you use type constraints to get compiler errors when the factory is handed a type it doesn't want to deal with?